# 'a user with that username already exists' is not in Django UserCreationForm anymore?

Tags: python, django

I'm studying Django and have come across a question.

In several of the Django Youtube Tutorials, I see the Youtuber using the UserCreationForm to create the signup page and then experimenting with the form to show the viewers about the page.

And there comes a time when they signups a user with perhaps a username "test1" and then tries to signup a user with the same username as "test1" and they get the error message 'a user with that username already exists'

However, when I've followed these tutorials, I see that there is no error message appearing anymore and it just pops up the original UserCreationForm again in the webpage.

Is this error message removed? And I've been looking through the Django Github files and the Django Documentation, but it doesn't mention anything about the username error, so... I'm thinking that it's removed, but I want to be sure.

*edit! I added the code to my question as below:

```
# views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse

def signup_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login()
            return redirect('articles:article_list')
    form = UserCreationForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', context)
```

```
# login.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <form class="site-form" action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you using the standard user model and user creation page template, or did you make your own?

Comment: share full code !!

Comment: Please add code to your question.

Comment: I'm using the standard user model! I added the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

It seems that the UserCreationForm does not print that error as default when the username already exists. When you try to print the error manually in order to check if the username already exists in the database, it works!